# Как правильно подключать свои стили параллельно с бутстраповскими?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Пытался подключить простейший внешний стиль:

```
body  {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Даже приоритет не помог выдавить бутстраповский стиль.

Скрин прикрепил:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: посмотрите пример - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/ocy242tL/ + для bootstrap есть такой сервис для настройки http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас ознакомлюсь

Comment: Так что с !important, почему не сработал ?

Comment: Это связано с тем,  что наследуемый стиль (в данном случае color) имеет низкий приоритет перед явно указанным стилем

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А цвет чего именно вы хотите поменять? Если ссылок в меню, то копируйте способ, которым задаётся стиль этого элемента в бутстрапе.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css');

/* так не работает */
body { color: red !important; }

/* а так пожалуйста */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a></div>
    <div id="bs-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="">Left</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="">Right</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Ещё грамотнее - оформить свой класс, чтобы использовать его вместе (или вместо) `.navbar-default`. Например, `.navbar-red`:

```css
.navbar-default.navbar-red .navbar-brand,
.navbar-default.navbar-red .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-red">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-navbar" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button><a href="" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a></div>
    <div id="bs-navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="">Left</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="">Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="">Right</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, сейчас буду пробовать. Скажите, а почему не сработало правило !important ? Разве оно не должно было максимизировать приоритет моего стиля ?!

Comment: Конкретизация элемента увеличивает приоритет стиля. Надо перечитать документацию, как именно, но думаю, дело в этом. Дополнил ответ замечанием о собственных классах стилей.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь: я стилизовал целевой класс и влепил это дело в хвост бутстраповского стиля. Работает. Наконец-то продолжу двигаться по курсу дальше.

Comment: Рад помочь. Если ответ закрывает вопрос, отметьте его решение. Для этого надо нажать галочку рядом с ответом, чтобы она стала зелёной.

Comment: Да я и раньше искал кнопку, чтобы отметить вопрос как решённый. Что-то не вижу я никакой галочки. Курсором вожу, ничего не появляется. Давно слыхал про это сообщество, но сам тут недавно.

Comment: ВСЁ, НАШЁЛ, ОТМЕТИЛ